# How to run batch file inside Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded to VS2022 I cannot find a way to start developer command prompt and run a batch file inside it. Previously I called `vsvars32.bat` and it set all variables and paths, allowing me to continue in my .bat file. In the current version it does not work and when I call `VsDevCmd.bat`, the rest of commands in my batch file are not executed.

Is there a way to call developer command prompt or set paths and variables from batch file and continue?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any other solution so ended up using pipe like this:

`type cmds.txt | "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual`

And `cmds.txt` contains batch file invocation:

`buildall.bat`

Not pretty, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to thank you and confirm that this was the only way to automate compilation of a C++ project trhough VS Code.

I tried setting up tasks.json in VS Code and multiple other setups but after 4 days of that nothing worked except your solution PiotrK.

So I ended up preparing a TXT file with a list of commands like so:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Users\DEKOLEV\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
cd "C:\path\to\some\folder\with\C++\source\code\files"
code .
```

}

and I piped the text file directly to the Developer Console link. So now I have a batch file containing the following

```
type "C:\Some\path\to\file\commands.txt" | "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2022\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022.lnk"
```

Starting the batch file starts the x64 developer command prompt and runs VS Code from it which enables VS Code to compile the source C++ files with the environment x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 provides.

I don't have enough points to post a comment so I am posting this feedback as an answer. :)